# Как изменить значение OverlapOperation в Light2D. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, light

Всех приветствую. Я имею свет, у которого мне требуется менять значение OverlapOperation с Additive к AlphaBlend. Ломаю голову - ничего не получается. Буду рад помощи!

В моём попытке показана лишь смена на Additive

Жалкие старания :

```cs
UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.Light2D.OverlapOperation = UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.Light2D.OverlapOperation.Additive;
```

Код Light2d:

```
public enum OverlapOperation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Colors are added together
    /// </summary>
    Additive,
    /// <summary>
    /// Colors are blended using standed blending (alpha, 1-alpha)
    /// </summary>
    AlphaBlend
    }

    [SerializeField] OverlapOperation m_OverlapOperation = OverlapOperation.Additive;
```

Ошибка:

> error CS0118: 'Light2D.OverlapOperation' is a type but is used like a variable